# Return the count of negative numbers in the optimal way

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array

A variation of "Searching in a Matrix that is sorted rowwise and columnwise"

Given a 2D Matrix that is sorted rowwise and columnwise. You have to return the count of negative numbers in most optimal way.

I could think of this solution

1. initialise rowindex=0
2. if rowindex>0 rowindex++

   else apply binary search

And implemented in with this code for 5X5 matrix

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int arr[5][5];

int func(int row)
{
    int hi=4;
    int lo=0;
    int mid=(lo+hi)/2;
    while(hi>=lo)
    {
        mid=(lo+hi)/2;
        .
        if(mid==4)
        {
            return 5;
        }
        if(arr[row][mid]<0 && arr[row][mid+1]<0)
        {
            lo=mid+1;
        }
        else if(arr[row][mid]>0 && arr[row][mid+1]>0)
        {
            hi=mid-1;
        }
        else if(arr[row][mid]<0 && arr[row][mid+1]>0)
        {
            return mid+1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ri,ci,sum;
    ri=0;   //rowindex
    ci=0;   //columnindex
    sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    while(ri<5)
    {
        if(arr[ri][ci]>=0)
        {
            ri++;
        }
        else if(arr[ri][ci]<0)
        {
            int p=func(ri);
            sum+=p;
            ri++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
}
```

I ran the code here http://ideone.com/PIlNd2
runtime O(xlogy) for a matrix of x rows and y columns

Correct me if i am wrong in time complexity or implementation of code

Does anyone have any better idea than this to improve Run-time complexity?

Comment: -ve number means a number less than zero

Comment: Just say negative, then.

Comment: Not very thoroughly. Shall we treat your question with the same level of attention?

Comment: sorry sir i would soon add some more details

Comment: For searching in sorted matrix use "Down-Left" approach.
Complexity : O(N) for NxN matrix

Comment: @prashant:not searching i am looking for the number of negative numbers

Comment: If you want an exact count, how can anything beat O(n)? Unless you change your data structure to keep track of the number of negative numbers on matrix cell changes.

Comment: @ syazdani:but how can searching help in counting the number of negative numbers and this is what i am asking

Comment: @ankur: You don't necessarily more details - just a moment's thought to your grammar and presentation would encourage us to care more about your problem.

Comment: @syazdani: The OP states that the matrix is sorted.  Therefore, you should be able to find the zero-crossing point in O(log n) time.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It's a *matrix*. Two-dimensional. Binary search isn't enough.

Comment: @user2357112: If I understand the question description, there must be a "rectangle" of negative values in the array.  Finding the "bottom-right" (and thus the size) of this rectangle should be doable in logarithmic time (I guess O(log(m+n)), not O(log n) as I previously stated).

Comment: It doesn't have to be a rectangle. Consider the following: `int[][] array = {{-2, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}};`.

Comment: @user2357112: That's a fair point ;)  Thus +1 for your answer (because I can't think how to beat it...)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:thanx and i would keep this thing in mind for future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O(m+n) algorithm, where m and n are the dimensions of the array, working by sliding down the top of the negative portion, finding the last negative number in each row. This is most likely what Prashant was talking about in the comments:

```
int negativeCount(int m, int n, int **array) {
    // array is a pointer to m pointers to n ints each.
    int count = 0;
    int j = n-1;
    for (int i = 0, i < m; i++) {
        // Find the last negative number in row i, starting from the index of
        // the last negative number in row i-1 (or from n-1 when i==0).
        while (j >= 0 && array[i][j] >= 0) {
            j--;
        }
        if (j < 0) {
            return count;
        }
        count += j+1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

We can't do better than worst-case O(m+n), but if you're expecting far fewer than m+n negative numbers, you may be able to get a better usual-case time.

Suppose you have an n by n array, where `array[i][j] < 0` iff `i < n-j`. In that case, the only way the algorithm can tell that `array[i][n-1-i] < 0` for any i is by looking at that cell. Thus, the algorithm has to look at at least n cells.

Comment: if this algo is of O(m+n) complexity then mine should be O(m+logn) complexity correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @ankur: You do a binary search for every single row, requiring O(mlog(n)) time if the entire array is negative. This algorithm might spend longer on some particular rows than yours, but the total time it spends on linear searches is O(n).

Comment: Detecting first sign change starting from top right corner, sliding down (when element less than zero then row++, else col--), this way most of matrix part could be skipped.

Comment: there must be a typo here. both i and j are relative to `n`

Comment: @UmNyobe: Yes indeed. Fixed.

Comment: @user2357112:i think your answer takes O(mn) in worst case??
and the solution that prashant mentioned in his comments is more like O(m+n)?

Comment: @ankur: Nope. It needs to step down at most `m` times and across at most `n` times. It might perform a lot of steps in any given row or column, but it will never perform a lot of steps in all the rows or all the columns, since neither counter resets to the beginning when the other advances. Thus, it's only O(m+n).

Answer (score 0):

You are conducting a binary search. Whereby you divide n by 2 to find the midpoint then continue to divide, before returning a value. That looks like a binary search, even though you are dividing columns for each row. Therefore, you are performing O(log n). Or something like O(x log n/y).