# Counting 1's in a n x n array of 0's and 1's

Tags: python, algorithm, count

Assuming that in each row of the array, all 1's come before the 0's, how would I be able to come up with an (O)nlogn algorithm to count the 1's in the array. I think first I would have to make a counter, search each row for 1's (n), and add that to the counter. Where does the "log n part" come into play? I read that a recursive algorithm to do this has nlogn complexity, but Im not too sure how I would do this. I know how to do this in O(n^2) with for loops. Pseudo code or hints would be helpful! Thank you

Comment: Do a binary search on each row for the last 1.

Comment: "I know how to do this in O(n) with for loops" So your outer loop runs n times and inner loop runs n times for each value of outer loop. Hence it becomes O(n^2), not O(n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all 1's come before the 0's, you can find the index of the first 0 using Binary search algorithm (which is log N) and you just have to do this for all the N rows. So the total complexity is NlogN.

Comment: it maybe smaller bigO ... but most of the time `row.index(0)+1` will probably beat binary search implemented in python(time-wise at least) ... at least I think so ... it would be interesting to test

Comment: also note that the binary search would have to search for a zero with a one immediately to the left of it, not just zero

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct, but OP has specifically asked for nlogn algorithm.

Comment: @user2357112 I included the O(N) version as well, please check now.

Comment: @thefourtheye: No, that's O(N^2); N is the side length, not the number of elements. Upon closer inspection of the question, it seems that the O(N) algorithm I had in mind doesn't work. I was thinking of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775580/return-the-count-of-negative-numbers-in-the-optimal-way , but that algorithm requires additional structure in the input; all columns must also be sorted.

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct, we can make use of the fact that 1s are consecutive. I updated the answer please check now.

Comment: @thefourtheye: No, binary search is still faster. Sorry for all the confusion; the algorithm I had in mind achieves O(n) performance by starting the search for each row from the position the previous search ended at, but that requires the positions of the last 1 in each row to form a monotonic sequence. We don't have that here.